# Read data from a RSS feed - getInputStream(); crash

Tags: android, rss, feed

Excuse me but I'm really newbie at Android. I'm following a online tutorial for dummies and following the instructions of the tutorial I tried to code a simple app that read a RSS feed and put all the items (title + link) in a ListView.

In Debug Mode I found that the crash happen in row 73

```
return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
```

This is my Main Activity (sorry for the Italian comment and multiple Log, I used it for debugging)

```
package com.example.readfrominternet;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    //definiamo le variabili
    ListView lvRss;
    ArrayList<String> titoli;
    ArrayList<String> link;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //assegniamo le variabili agli oggetti
        lvRss = findViewById(R.id.lvRss);
        titoli = new ArrayList<String>();
        link = new ArrayList<String>();

        //specifichiamo cosa fare quando clicchiamo sul singolo item
        lvRss.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                Log.v("MAIN", "Abbiamo cliccato sul singlo item, riga 54");
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(link.get(position));
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
                Log.v("MAIN", "Abbiamo aperto il link sul browser, riga 58");

            }
        });

        new ProcessInBackground().execute();
        Log.v("MAIN", "Abbiamo eseguito il processo in background, riga 64");
    }

    //definiamo il metodo per fare lo streaming del file
    public InputStream getInputStream(URL url)
    {
        Log.v("MAIN", "Siamo all'interno del getInputStream, riga 70");
        try
        {
            return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

            return null;
        }
    }

    public class ProcessInBackground extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Exception>
    {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        Exception exception = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog.setMessage("Busy loading RSS feed, please wait!");
            progressDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Exception doInBackground(Integer... params    )
        {
            Log.v("MAIN", "Siamo nel doInBackground, riga 99");
            try
            {

                //servono per il parsing
                URL url = new URL("http://feeds.news24.com/articles/fin24/tech/rss");
                XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
                XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
                xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");  //UTF_8 è il tipo di encoding utilizzato per il testo
                Log.v("MAIN", "Siamo nel setting dello streaming, riga 109");
                //serve a capire quando sono all'interno dell'item che voglio leggere
                boolean insideItem = false;

                // la variabile eventType ci aiuta a capire se il tag che stiamo leggendo è un tag di apertura o di chiusura, etc.
                int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
                Log.v("MAIN", "Recuperiamo il tipo dell'evento, riga 115");

                while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
                {
                    Log.v("MAIN", "Siamo dentro il while, riga 119");
                    if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                    {
                        if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
                        {
                            insideItem = true;
                        }
                        else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
                        {
                            if(insideItem)
                            {
                                titoli.add(xpp.nextText());
                            }
                        }
                        else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link"))
                        {
                        if(insideItem)
                            {
                            link.add(xpp.nextText());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
                    {
                        insideItem = false;
                    }
                    eventType = xpp.next();
                }

            }
            catch(XmlPullParserException e)
            {
                exception = e;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
            catch(MalformedURLException e)
            {
                exception = e;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }catch(IOException e)
            {
                exception = e;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
            return exception;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Exception s)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Log.v("MAIN", "Siamo nell'onPostExecute, riga 171");
            //settiamo la lista con gli articoli letti
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titoli);
            lvRss.setAdapter(adapter);
            Log.v("MAIN", "Settimao l'adapter della lista, riga 175");

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.v("MAIN", "Dismettiamo il progress dialog, riga 178");
        }

    }

}
```

This is the error i read on the Logcat windows:

```
2019-10-21 18:08:42.873 14570-14570/com.example.readfrominternet E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.readfrominternet.MainActivity has leaked window DecorView@5ba2a72[MainActivity] that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:511)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:346)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:329)
        at com.example.readfrominternet.MainActivity$ProcessInBackground.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:92)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:648)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:595)
        at com.example.readfrominternet.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:63)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I correctly used the permission on android-manifest.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: To solve your current problem, declare and init your progressDialog in Main Activity.
Not inside Asynctask class.
Also your ProcessInBackground is inner class. so ProcessInBackground should be static else memory leak will occur.
App is crashing in this line
xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:
This is my activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IRssCallback
{

    ListView lvRss;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private ArrayList<String> link;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lvRss = findViewById(R.id.lvRss);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        lvRss.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                Log.v("MAIN", "Abbiamo cliccato sul singlo item, riga 54");
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(link.get(position));
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
                Log.v("MAIN", "Abbiamo aperto il link sul browser, riga 58");

            }
        });

        new ProcessInBackground(this).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgress(boolean loading) {
        if(loading) {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Busy loading RSS feed, please wait!");
            progressDialog.show();
        }else{
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(ArrayList<String> list,ArrayList<String> link) {
        this.link = link;
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        lvRss.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I have created a separate class for **`ProcessInBackground`**

```
public class ProcessInBackground extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, ArrayList<String>>
{

    private WeakReference<IRssCallback> listener;
    public ProcessInBackground(IRssCallback listener){
        this.listener = new WeakReference<IRssCallback>(listener);
    }
    private ArrayList<String> titoli = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList<String> link = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        listener.get().onProgress(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Integer... params)
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL("http://feeds.news24.com/articles/fin24/tech/rss");
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            InputStream inputStream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
            xpp.setInput(inputStream, "UTF_8");
            boolean insideItem = false;

            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

            while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
            {
                if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                {
                    if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
                    {
                        insideItem = true;
                    }
                    else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
                    {
                        if(insideItem)
                        {
                            titoli.add(xpp.nextText());
                        }
                    }
                    else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link"))
                    {
                        if(insideItem)
                        {
                            link.add(xpp.nextText());
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
                {
                    insideItem = false;
                }
                eventType = xpp.next();
            }

        }
        catch(XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  titoli;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> list) {
        super.onPostExecute(list);
        listener.get().onSuccess(list, link);
    }

}
```

For passing callback from `ProcessInBackground` to `MainActivity` , I have create interface( `IRssCallback`)

```
public interface IRssCallback {

    void onProgress(boolean loading);
    void onSuccess(ArrayList<String> list,ArrayList<String> link);
    void onError(Exception e);
}
```